# What low height plants have a good root system?

Tags: plant-recommendations, ground-cover

I need to remove a bunch of junk weeds / trees on my sloping property blocking a beautiful view. I realize the root system is preventing some erosion into the nearby lake. I plan to cut at the trunk.

What low height plants can be used in replacement that has a good root system as well?

Comment: Search "soil erosion control plants".

Comment: You are probably not the only person with such idea on your city. Look around (it depend on how steep is your sloping property, but also about soil and climate [and how much rain you may get in a short amount of time]). Grass is often sufficient (but the trick is the period until grass is grow up sufficiently. If the soil is very wet, you may need to so drainage. In short: it depends on too much data, we do not have. (not considering your preferences)